# Naming tar archive the same as source file

Tags: linux, tar

Simply enough I want to create an archive from a file and preserve the file name.

```
File = host1.log
Tar  = Archive_date_host1.tar.gz
```

I'm using it like this:

```
find /var/log/TESTIN/ -daystart -mtime 7 -type f | xargs tar -czPf /var/log/TESTOUT/ARCHIVE_$(date +%F)_FILENAMEHERE.tar.gz
```

The "archive" and date portions I can do, but is there a way to grab the filename and use it?  I've googled a bunch and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the [basename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/basename.html) of each file as the variable portion of the output file, that is, remove the directory portion of the name and the `.log` suffix. Try this:

```
find /var/log/TESTIN/ -daystart -mtime 7 -type f | \
xargs -I {} sh -c 'tar -czPf /var/log/TESTOUT/ARCHIVE_$(date +%F)_$(basename {} .log).tar.gz {}'
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Just a quick follow up question. I haven't used xargs so I'm still learning. What does the sh -c do exactly?

Comment: The sh -c command takes a string as an argument and runs it as a shell command, performing all the customary things such as command substitution (`$(...)`). xargs can run any single command, but it doesn't necessarily use a shell to do so, and trying to nest commands - asking xargs to run `basename {}` and using its output to form part of a `tar` command - would likely be kind of messy using xargs alone; it's easier just to have a shell do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I think just `find` should be enough for that. For example, following command creates a `.tar.gz` archive out of every file found with the naming scheme you wanted. Note that `{}` is replaced by found file's name,

```
find * -type f -exec tar -czf ARCHIVE_$(date +%F)_{}.tar.gz {} \;
```

Comment: The key here is using `-exec`, which gives you access to each thing that `find` located.